# Attempting to recursively export members of OUs and output them to CSVs in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I've been trying for hours to create a script that outputs the members within each OU and saves that list of members to a document with the title of the OU.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$COU = Import-CSV C:\Users\hp\COU.csv foreach ($OU in $COU) {Get-ADUser 
-filter * -searchbase "OU=$($COU.OU),OU=TestOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET"} 
| Foreach ($_) {Export-CSV "C:\Users\hp\$($COU.OU).csv"}
```

I keep getting errors that the directory cannot be found, no matter what formatting I use when attempting to get the info from the OUs I get those errors, and I get even more when attempting the export.

The CSV is formatted like so:
**OU**
FirstOU
SecondOU
ThirdOU
...

Getting the list of users does work without the variable if I just type the name of the OU and if I "Write-Output" the variable I get the names of the OUs so I'm guess the issue relates to how to properly insert the variable into the string.

This is my first post so apologies for any formatting errors, please let me know and I can correct them.

I also though instead of importing the CSV I could use the following command:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPfilter "(ou=*)" -searchbase "OU=TestOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET"
```

Answer (score 1):

This one's simple. You define your `ForEach` loop to be `ForEach($OU in $COU)` but then within the loop you continue to reference `$COU` instead of `$OU`. This could be simplified even more though by simply expanding the OU property when you import the CSV, and working with an array of strings instead.

```
$COU = Import-CSV C:\Users\hp\COU.csv | Select -Expand OU
ForEach ($OU in $COU){
    Get-ADUser -filter * -searchbase "OU=$OU,OU=TestOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET" | Export-CSV "C:\Users\hp\OU.csv" -NoType
}
```